# How to fix this problem? Login if statement not working

Tags: python, django

This is my views.py

```
def user_login(request):
   if request.method == "POST":
    username = request.POST.get('username')  
    password = request.POST.get('password')  
    user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
    if user:
        if user.is_active:
            login(request, user)
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('index'))
        else:
            return HttpResponse("Your account is Inactive.")
    else:
        return HttpResponse("Invalid User Credentials Provided!!!!")
else:
    return render(request, "MyTestApp/login.html", {})
```

And this is my login page:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="jumbotron">
    <h2 class="text-dark"> Login </h2>
    <form method="post" action="{ url 'MyTestApp:user_login '}">
        {%csrf_token%}
        <label for="username"> Username </label>
        <input type="text" name="username" placeholder=" Write Your UserName Here"> <br></br>

        <label for="password"> Password </label>
        <input type="text" name="password" placeholder=" Write Your Password Here"> <br></br>

        <input  type="submit" class="btn btn-dark" name="savebutton" value="login">
    </form>
</div>
```

When I try to login it works. If I try to login with a unregistered account then it doesn't allow me returns the message "Invalid User Credentials Provided", which is good. But When I try to login with a inactive account it still returns "Invalid User Credentials Provided". It doesn't return the message "Your account is Inactive.", which it should return when I login with a inactive account. Does anyone know why this is happening. Any help will be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As `authenticate` returns `None` if the account is inactive, you can't know if the account is inactive or the user does not exist. You have to check yourself the status of the user:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, reverse
from django.contrib.auth import login, get_user_model
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect

def user_login(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        username = request.POST.get('username')
        password = request.POST.get('password')

        try:
            user_model = get_user_model()
            user = user_model.objects.get(username=username)
            if not user.is_active:
                return HttpResponse("Your account is Inactive.")

            if not user.check_password(password):
                return HttpResponse("Invalid User Credentials Provided!!!!")

            login(request, user)
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('index'))
        except user_model.DoesNotExist:
            return HttpResponse("User does not exist!!!!")

    else:
        return render(request, "MyTestApp/login.html", {})
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because you are using ModelBackend Authentication which is default for Django. This backend checks if user can authenticate by checking if user is_active. Your user is not active, so it can't authenticate, so your `authenticate` returns None instead of User. If you want to know more about this authentication method check it `django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend`.

Answer (score 0):

Since default `authenticate` always validate for `username` and `password` with `is_active` status that's why `authenticate` always returns `None` if user is inactive. You can make your own `CustomLoginBackend` and check for `username` and `password` and return `user` object if `username` and `password` correct otherwise returns `None` and check if user is `active` or not in your `views.py`

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

class CustomLoginBackend(object):

    def authenticate(self, request, username, password):
        User = get_user_model()
        try:
            user = User.objects.using(db_name).get(username=username)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return None
        else:
            if password is not None:
                if  user.check_password(password):
                    return user
        return None
```

Then in your `login` views.

```
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.urls import reverse
from django.shortcuts import render

def user_login(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        username = request.POST.get('username')  
        password = request.POST.get('password')  
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            if user.is_active:
                login(request, user)
                return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('index'))
            else:
                return HttpResponse("Your account is Inactive.")
        else:
            return HttpResponse("Invalid User Credentials Provided!!!!")
    else:
        return render(request, "MyTestApp/login.html", {})
```

And at last don't forgot to add `AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS` in your `settings.py` as

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = ['path_to_your.CustomLoginBackend ',]
```